# Laravel 5.1 and Iron.io

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, iron.io

I just updated a project to 5.1 yesterday and noticed that Queue::marshal() has been deprecated: Iron.io "push queues" have been deprecated in favor of typical Iron.io queues and queue listeners. Okay, great - so how exactly do I use "typical iron.io queues?" The project is configured for Iron push queues.

I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation regarding Iron apart from how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you forgot to update ironmq version after switching to Laravel 5.1. Only [IronMQ v4](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php) is compatible with Laravel 5.1. Specify "4.*" as IronMQ version in composer.json.